# How do I save my HTML document using SaveFile.js?

Tags: javascript, save

I'm trying to allow for a save feature on my webpage. I'm using the 'SaveFile.js' module found here: 'https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/' When a user clicks the save button, the document should download itself as an HTML file with all of its elements like input boxes, pictures etc. However, what gets downloaded isn't the full HTML document. Just some text on an HTML page:

[image: HTML file with just text on it]

Why is this happening?

```
<button type="button" name="btnSave" onclick="saveHTMLFile()">Save</button>

<script>
  function saveHTMLFile(){
  let fileToSave=document;
  let blob = new Blob([fileToSave],{type:"text/html;charset=utf-8"});
  saveAs(blob,'SavedOutline.html')
}
  </script>
```

Comment: The `document` object is an object representing the DOM, not a string of HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to serialize the document as a string.
Try using `document.documentElement.outerHTML` instead of just `document`.

- [`document.documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement) will give you the root element of the document
- [`el.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) will give you the html of the element as string

In your code:

```html
<button type="button" name="btnSave" onclick="saveHTMLFile()">Save</button>

<script>
  function saveHTMLFile(){
  let fileToSave=document.documentElement.outerHTML;
  let blob = new Blob([fileToSave],{type:"text/html;charset=utf-8"});
  saveAs(blob,'SavedOutline.html')
}
  </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if it will help, but you can try this peace of code.

```js
var file = new File(["Hello, world!"], "hello world.txt", {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
FileSaver.saveAs(file);
```

When you are using new Blob() documentation says it is only for `Saving text`

Comment: That doesn't help, because the problem is in getting the HTML as a string. You've throw the HTML away and have a hardcoded string.